# Unknown receiver 'dynamoDBObjectMapper' did you mean 'AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper'?

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to implement AWS DynamoDB scan in objective C.

I am getting an error but I am not sure whats causing it:

```
Unknown receiver 'dynamoDBObjectMapper' did you mean 'AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper'?
```

The problem line is highlighted in the code:

```
#import "ScanTable.h"
#import "Mapper.h"

        @implementation ScanTable

        void scanTableDo () {
            AWSDynamoDBScanExpression *scanExpression = [AWSDynamoDBScanExpression new];
            scanExpression.limit = @10;

            [[dynamoDBObjectMapper scan:[Mapper class]
                             expression:scanExpression] /// Problem here
             continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {
                 if (task.error) {
                     NSLog(@"The request failed. Error: [%@]", task.error);
                 }
                 if (task.exception) {
                     NSLog(@"The request failed. Exception: [%@]", task.exception);
                 }
                 if (task.result) {
                     AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput *paginatedOutput = task.result;
                     for (Mapper *book in paginatedOutput.items) {
                         //Do something with book.
                     }
                 }
                 return nil;
             }];


        }

        @end
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Where is declared `dynamoDBObjectMapper`?

Comment: you were not declared the `dynamoDBObjectMapper` in your class

Comment: You are right thank deleting repeated